# Avoiding/Resolving duplicate classes in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies, duplicates, pom.xml

I have one huge project A and which has dependency project B (which is not in our control).
The problem is when I include B under A project pom.xml, everything is fine and the build is successful.

But in few of the areas, where we are facing runtime exceptions due to duplicated classes.

Project A has it's own JDom dependency version and Project B is using different/Same JDom version. During application run time, it's thowring InvocationTarget exception due to conflicting classes.

How do I ensure, project A uses it's own jdom while project B uses it's own or atleast resolving such conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the (transitive) dependency from your project B which is being imported.

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>ProjectB</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>jdom</groupId>
          <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The above example will cause your Project B dependency to be pulled in, sans its version of the JDOM library.